# What does this phrase mean? "free me swag out."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang, australian-english

This is from a native Australian English speaker [Australian accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnioDeQNlxQ) (see: 3:46-3:55)

> Free me swag out, camped under the stars, and I was healed up.

I couldn't understand **"free me swag out."**.

I looked up **"swag"** meaning stolen goods which makes no sense here.

Then I looked up **"free out"** thinking that maybe **"out"** belongs to the word **"free"**, but again no such thing.

Then I looked up the whole phrase **"free me swag out"**, and no such phrase.

So, it does not seem to make any sense for us non-natives.

Really, what does it mean?

Comment: The mixed tenses (Present ***free***, Past ***camped, was healed up***) are just because it's a "syntactically sloppy" conversational context. Same applies to the (widespread, but "ungrammatical") use of non-possessive ***me*** rather than ***my***. Be careful about copying the vocabulary *or* the syntax of this speaker, though. *He* sounds completely natural, but you copying it as a non-native speaker might not.

Comment: Swag means tent. It's that simple.

Comment: Yunus, there's a famous Aussie song "Up jumped the swag-man ..." (google). A swagman being (basically) a camper or hiker .. a vagabond outdoorsman.

Comment: @Fattie The song is Waltzing Matilda. The one song every non-Australian should know., :)

Comment: @Lambie right on!  I just meant "type this quoted phrase, containing 'swag',  in to a computer to find it ..."  :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: After listening a few times I think it's actually "**threw** my swag out", but the subtitling has got confused by the accent - which makes more sense to me and, as you point out, otherwise the tenses don't align.

Comment: @psmears: You're absolutely right (I *did* listen to it yesterday, but I didn't notice that; OP's text here and Youtube's subtitling threw me off). But my actual point clearly applies to the speaker's *preceding* utterance - *First thing, **get** off the plane, mate, **didn't** go home...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yep, no arguing with that one :)

Comment: Yes and by the way, what was the swagman's name?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

'Free **me** swag out' = 'unpack **my** canvas bed roll with a mattress inside'

A 'swag' (countable noun) is a traditional Australian canvas bed roll with a mattress inside, carried rolled up by hikers or people who wish to 'sleep under the stars' in the Australian outback. It is carried rolled-up e.g. in a backpack or motor vehicle, and unrolled at a sleeping location.

Swag (as a non-countable noun) is a term used for stolen goods being carried away from where their owner had placed them (often in a bag or sack). By the 1830s it had come, in Australia, to also mean the possessions carried by a person travelling in the outback.

[Swag (bedroll) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swag_(bedroll))

[What is a swag?](https://sightseeingtoursaustralia.com.au/tips-articles/what-is-a-swag/)

[image]

Comment: No wonder I, as an American, thought this was utter gibberish

Comment: Having listened a few times I think it may actually be "**threw** my swag out" (with the subtitles getting confused by the accent).

Comment: The word 'swag' is also used in the US to mean free stuff that is given out e.g.: at vendor booths at a conference.  I've heard it's for 'stuff we all get' but that could be a bacronym.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, considering what psmears and FumbleFingers said above, do you also think that it could be "threw my swag out" rather than "free me swag out"? What do you think?

Comment: @yunus - it isn't clear, but I think it is '**threw** me swag out'.

Comment: @JimmyJames - when my employer moved offices, they decided it was too much trouble to transport all of the stationery store to the new location, easier to order new stuff to be delivered there. They said to the staff, 'take what you want', so people grabbed packs of paper, Post-It notes, ballpoint pens, etc. We called that our 'swag'.

Comment: @JimmyJames "could be a backronym" is a very generous way of looking at it.  That's one of the most blatantly preposterous claims I've ever heard.

Comment: Where I worked, we usually called the stuff we got at conferences 'freebies'. Mostly rubbish, like branded cheap pens, pads of sticky notes, lanyards for our passes, etc. My boss got a 'stress toy' which was a little black-and-white dog made of slightly spongy rubber. The idea was that you could get stress relief by scrunching him up in your hand. I was intrigued to see how often, and how severely, 'Spotty' got mangled up. Eventually his head came off. One sarcastic person suggested giving him a funeral.

Comment: I was that person.

Comment: @phoog Googling, it does seem to be a fairly popular misconception.  Snopes have probably done the best summary.  With one meaning of "swag" being "a bag of stuff, possibly stolen", that fits perfectly with the context of promotional items.

Comment: @phoog I'm pretty sure I heard Michael Scott say 'swag' means 'stuff we all get' on an old episode of 'The Office' (US)

Comment: @JimmyJames - I once heard a guy on a TV show say that 'FBI means 'Female Body Inspector', but that does not make it so. Anyhow, it's 'swag', not 'SWAG'.

Comment: @JimmyJames I have not seen much of The Office (neither version), but I would be surprised if there aren't at least a few preposterous claims in every episode.  The reason I find it preposterous is the fact that "swag" meant "stuff" for a couple of centuries before it was applied to contexts where "we all get" makes any sense.  (But it's not quite as egregiously wrong as another folk etymology involving the word "carnal," where the word being explained has been in the English language since long before the word "carnal" was borrowed.)

Comment: @phoog I'm not sure why people are taking this as some sort of claim that this is true.  The fact is that people make this claim, not that it's a true claim.  I don't think that is the real etymology just as I don't think 'for unlawful carnal knowledge' is the real etymology for any word.  Regardless, the word 'swag' has a commonly used meaning in the US which is different than what is described in this answer.  I think that is useful to know for ELL.